# Adding option to increase bass of a youtube video

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

I am trying to add video to my website. Apart from adding the video, I also want an option to increase or decrease the bass of the audio. I fetched the Youtube API but could not find any way to do it. Any ideas if it can be done with JavaScript?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

There aren't any supported JavaScript APIs for manipulating the audio (or visual elements) of a YouTube video.